# Is there a way to collect references of objects on the heap of a particular type?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, heap-memory

(Short version.)

Is there a way my C# code can access a collection of objects on the managed heap without keeping my own collection of references?

(Long version.)

I've written an immutable object class. While profiling, I found my code had created many duplicate objects. Separate instances of my class but storing the same contents.

To reduce the burden of storing all these duplicates, I took a tip from the `String` class and thought about writing my own `Intern` facility. This way, before an instance is taken into a collection to be stored for the long term, I would first check a pool of values and see if an equivalent object is already in the pool and if so, return the pooled reference to replace the supplied reference which can be quickly GC'd away.

I thought about how it would work and imagined a collection of `WeakReference` wrappers to hold the pooled references. It was at this point I realized my code would be keeping a redundant collection of objects. The heap manager in dot-net is already keeping track of all the objects to allow the GC to work.

So rather than maintain a pool, could I ask the dot-net heap manager to please give me a collection of references to all the instances of a particular type on the heap?

Comment: Short answer: no. (At least not without getting involved in profiling APIs etc.)

Comment: The system doesn't *actively* maintain a collection of references. The mark phase of GC is about following references from a set of roots.

Comment: @JonSkeet long answer: "nooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo"